# webView.loadRequest() not correctly loading webpage in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two ViewControllers, which I am trying to pass a `NSURLRequest` through a delegate.
Here is the delegate:

```
protocol URLRequestDelegate{

    func urlRequest(url: NSURLRequest)
}
```

The delegate is successfully passing the `NSURLRequest`, because I have error checked it.
However in the ViewController the delegate is passing the `NSURLRequest` to, I have implemented the required function to conform to the protocol which is where I use the function `webView.loadRequest()` to load the webView with the desired webpage.

The webView is done through code and not storyboard:

```
var webView: UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
```

Here is that function:

```
func urlRequest(url: NSURLRequest) {

    //Load URL from the delegate.
    webView.loadRequest(url)
}
```

But this does't load the UIWebView with the `NSURLRequest` passed in the delegate, I am thinking that the delegate method `func urlRequest()` isn't calling correctly or maybe before `viewDidLoad()` method.

I have even set the `self.view.webView.delegate = self`and implemented the `UIWebViewDelegate` on this class and implemented the `func viewDidStartLoad()` & `fun viewDidFinishLoad` with `println()` inside them to check to see if the codes being run when I call `webView.loadRequest(url)` however they never seem to be printed of.

So this leaves me puzzled, because I'm not quite sure what is causing the `.loadRequest()` not to function correctly within the delegate method `func urlRequest()`.

I do know that if I put `.loadRequest()` within `viewDidLoad()` with lets say a hardcoded url of `http://www.google.com` it does work. However I can't pass the delegates `NSURLRequest` within `viewDidLoad()` as it has to be implemented inside `func urlRequest()` to conform correctly to the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to set the delegate for your first ViewController? You first ViewController needs to have a property of type URLRequestDelegate and you need to set that property equal to your second ViewController at some point.